# convert select query to linq on sql server 2008

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have two tables: `Album(AlbumId, AlbumName)` and `Photo(PhotoId, PhotoName, AlbumId)`

I have :

```
 select top 1 Photo.PhotoId
 from Photo
 where Album.AlbumId=Photo.AlbumId
 order by NEWID()
```

This is return one record random

I want convert it to `Linq to sql`. I tried but not success.

Comment: yes.I was tried.I begin study for Linq.Please help me!

Comment: you need to use linq join.

Comment: Please show what you tried. Then we know what "not success" means.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to join the tables.  Also, it depends on what language you are using when you want to create a random Guid - my example uses C#.  In query syntax, it should be something like:

```
from p in Photo
join a in Album on a.AlbumId equals p.AlbumId
orderby Guid.NewGuid()
take 1
select p.PhotoId
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var photoId = ( from photo in collecPhotos
                join album in collecAlbums on photo.AlbumId equals album.AlbumId
                orderby NEWID()
                select photo.PhotoId).First();
```

where `collecPhotos` and `collecAlbums` are the collection of your Photo and Album entity i.e. data from the  tables. so it can also be `myDbContext.Photos` and `myDbContext.Albums` where `myDbContext` is your `Linq-to-Sql` DataContext.